# Find common substrings in a column using SQL

Tags: sql, distinct

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will be able to provide most frequent stored messages. For example there is a database that is storing several messages on a specific subject. Not all user have the same message stored.

```
id | name | comment
-------------------------------
1  | John | catching
2  | Bill | assistance with catching
```

Example above shows a table that I would like to distinguish from. Those 2 are the same category of catching. Need an SQL query that would know this is the same and would only display once

Comment: Like a `DISTINCT` query perhaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562295/find-common-substrings

Comment: How is it supposed to determine "same"-ness?  Is "catching" the same as "likes catching" or "has nothing to do with catching"?  How should it know which word(s) to key on?  If it can pick any word, you could very easily end up with everything in the "the" category.

Comment: With a DISTINCT query its gonna be looking at the identical comment.

Comment: @Becuzz I can try to assign a keyword, in this case catching. Could there be a query that would have different keywords to look for?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can specify a list of keywords to match on, you could do something like this:

```
declare @keywords table
(
    word varchar(100)
)
insert into @keywords values ('catching')
insert into @keywords values ('unicorns')

select kw.word, count(*) as NumMessages
from your_table t
inner join @keywords kw on t.comment like '%' + kw.word + '%'
group by kw.word
order by NumMessages
```

Note that if a comment contains more than one of the keywords it will show up in the count for both.